# get radio value with javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

hello everyone I can't get the radio input value here is my code :
the alert isn't running 
I want to do a real time calculation that shows the total to pay and I couldn't handle the radio values I appreciate your help thanks :D

```js
function transfer()
{
  var vip=document.getElementByName('mercedes');
  for (var i = 0, length = vip.length; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (vip[i].checked)
    {
     
     alert(vip[i].value);

     
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label  for="f1-about-yourself">Mercedes VIP transfer*:</label> <br>
<input  type="radio" name="mercedes" id="yes" value="yes"
onclick="transfer()">
<label  for="yes">Yes:</label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input  type="radio" name="mercedes" id="no" value="no" checked="" onclick="transfer()">
<label  for="no">No:</label>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementByName` is not a valid function, perhaps you meant: `getElementsByName` (plural elements)

Comment: thanks alot musefan <3

Comment: Keep an eye on the browser console (F12 in most browsers) when debugging issues, the error in there would have pointed out the problem for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
function transfer()
{
  var vip=document.getElementsByName('mercedes');
  for (var i = 0, length = vip.length; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (vip[i].checked)
    {
     
     alert(vip[i].value);

     
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label  for="f1-about-yourself">Mercedes VIP transfer*:</label> <br>
<input  type="radio" name="mercedes" id="yes" value="yes"
onclick="transfer()">
<label  for="yes">Yes:</label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input  type="radio" name="mercedes" id="no" value="no"  onclick="transfer()">
<label  for="no">No:</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already given answer that did fix the OP's problem the OP might think about separation of markup and code, thus not using inline code within html element markup.

Making use of the html `form` element that then hosts specific form controls like `input`, `button` etc. is highly advised too. Making
use of the *"DOM Level 0"* form collection also is not outdated. Event delegation as provided with the next example for instance helps if there will be other controls added to a form dynamically - one does not need to take care about registering event handlers to each newly appended form control. And last, registering to 'change' events will capture every change to the radio collection ...

```js
function isMercedesTransferType(elmNode) {
  return ((elmNode.type === 'radio') && (elmNode.name === 'mercedes'));
}
function handleVipTransferChange(evt) {
  var elmNode = evt.target;
  if (isMercedesTransferType(elmNode) && elmNode.checked) {
    console.log('handleVipTransferChange [name, value] : ', elmNode.name, elmNode.value);
  }
}

function initializeVipTransfer() {
  document.forms['mercedes-vip-transfer'].addEventListener('change', handleVipTransferChange, false);
}

initializeVipTransfer();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 70px; }
```

```html
<form class="form-group" name="mercedes-vip-transfer">
  <legend>Mercedes VIP transfer*:</legend>
  <label>
    <input  type="radio" name="mercedes" value="yes">
    <span>Yes</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input  type="radio" name="mercedes" value="no">
    <span>No</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Another way of dealing with initializing the required form controls directly will be demonstrated hereby ...

```js
function isMercedesTransferType(elmNode) {
  return ((elmNode.type === 'radio') && (elmNode.name === 'mercedes'));
}
function handleVipTransferChange(evt) {
  var elmNode = evt.target;
  if (elmNode.checked) {
    console.log('handleVipTransferChange [name, value] : ', elmNode.name, elmNode.value);
  }
}

function initializeVipTransfer() {
  var list = document.forms['mercedes-vip-transfer'].elements['mercedes'];
  Array.from(list).filter(isMercedesTransferType).forEach(function (elmNode) {
    elmNode.addEventListener('change', handleVipTransferChange, false);
  });
}

initializeVipTransfer();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 70px; }
```

```html
<form class="form-group" name="mercedes-vip-transfer">
  <legend>Mercedes VIP transfer*:</legend>
  <label>
    <input  type="radio" name="mercedes" value="yes">
    <span>Yes</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input  type="radio" name="mercedes" value="no">
    <span>No</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

... and just in order to round it up, if there is an *"up to date"* DOM, one might consider making use of modern DOM queries via [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and/or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) ...

```js
function handleVipTransferChange(evt) {
  var elmNode = evt.target;
  if (elmNode.checked) {
    console.log('handleVipTransferChange [name, value] : ', elmNode.name, elmNode.value);
  }
}

function initializeVipTransfer() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll('#mercedes-vip-transfer [type="radio"][name="mercedes"]');
  Array.from(list).forEach(function (elmNode) {
    elmNode.addEventListener('change', handleVipTransferChange, false);
  });
}

initializeVipTransfer();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 70px; }
```

```html
<form class="form-group" id="mercedes-vip-transfer">
  <legend>Mercedes VIP transfer*:</legend>
  <label>
    <input  type="radio" name="mercedes" value="yes">
    <span>Yes</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input  type="radio" name="mercedes" value="no">
    <span>No</span>
  </label>
</form>
```